# Error in Parsing data to listview

Tags: android, listview

NullPointerException on line 63 and 23. I'm getting frustrated in this. I followed every letter in the tutorial. but still getting errors. Please help. Once I'm done in this parsing thing, I'm now positive to graduate. I really need help.

Tutorial I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPJxnQpb_Vk&t=1501s

My Parser.java

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> {

Context c;
ListView lv;
String data;

ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressDialog pd;

public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.data = data;
    this.lv = lv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parser");
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {


    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if(integer == 1)
    {
        //ADAPTER
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Snackbar.make(view,categories.get(position),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    pd.dismiss();
}

//PARSE RECEIVED DATA
private int parse(){
    try
    {

        //ADD TGAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);

        //CREATE JO OBJECT TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
        JSONObject jo = null;

        categories.clear();

        //LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
        for(int i =0 ; i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            //RETRIEVE NAME
            String name=jo.getString("cat_name");
            //ADD TO ARRAY LIST
            categories.add(name);

        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

}

Line 63 is the "lv.setAdapter(adapter);"
Line 23 is the "public class Parser extends AsyncTask "

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/dbtest/categories.php";


FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final Downloader d = new Downloader(this,url,lv);
    d.execute();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);





}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.search_menu) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_user) {
        User_Fragment user_fragment =  new User_Fragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragment,
                user_fragment,
                user_fragment.getTag()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

The Downloader is working fine

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer, String> {

Context c;
String address;
ListView lv;

ProgressDialog pd;

public Downloader(Context c, String address, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.address = address;
    this.lv = lv;
}

//BEFORE JOB STARTS
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Fetch Data");
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String data = downloadData();
    return data;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(s != null){

        Parser p =new Parser(c,s,lv);
        p.execute();

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to download data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private String downloadData(){

    //connect and get a stream

    InputStream is = null;
    String line = null;

    try{

        URL url =  new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        is = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        if(br != null){

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(is != null){
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.lv)` is returning null. In which layout is the `ListView` with ID `lv`?

Comment: btw I have a fragment in my tabbed layout. I'm now trying to put the code in MainActivity to the fragment class. The listview is in my fragment_primary.xml. Maybe that's what I must do right?